# Почему в данном коде неправильно выполняется округление

Tags: java, double, округление

Цель программы - округлить число до 0.25 в меньшую сторону.
Вместо 123.25 получается 123, не могу понять, в чём проблема.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double b = 123.3;
        int n = 4;
        int c = (int) b;
        double x = b % c;
        double a;
        double d;
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            a = i / n;
            d = (i + 1) / n;
            if ((x > a) && (x < d)) {
                b = c + a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваша программа ничего не выводит.

Comment: `Math.floor(4 * x) / 4`

Comment: Сайт обрезал скобки, возможно из-за этого. Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема кода, представленного в вопросе, в том, что неправильно вычисляются `a` и `d` в цикле: так как оба операнда -- целые числа, то и результат будет *целочисленным*, то есть `a` и `d` будут принимать только значения 0 и 1, которые будут затем приводиться в тип `double`, вместо ожидаемых величин c шагом `1/n = 0.25`: `0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75`.

Кроме того, цикл должен выполняться для значений от 0 до `n`, иначе не будет правильно выполняться округление для чисел с дробями от `[0; 1/n)`.  Следует заметить, что при попадании в нужный диапазон, можно выйти досрочно из цикла.

Исправленное решение в виде отдельной функции может выглядеть так:

```java
public static double floorToNth(double x, int n) {
    int whole = (int) x;
    double fract = x - whole;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double a = (double) i / n;
        double b = (i + 1.0) / n;
        if (a < fract && fract < b) {
            return whole + a;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

При возврате значения `whole + b` получится округление к большему (*ceiling*).

Тест и сравнение с решением от @StanislavVolodarskiy:

```java
public static double floorToNthSimple(double x, int n) {
    return Math.floor(x * n) / n;
}

public static void main(String ... args) {
    double[] arr = {123d, 123.11, 123.25, 123.3, 123.48, 123.5, 123.72, 123.75, 123.86};
    for (var d : arr) {
        System.out.println(d + "\t" + floorToNth(d, 4) + "\tsimple=" + floorToNthSimple(d, 4));
    }
}
```

Результаты:

```
123.0   123.0   simple=123.0
123.11  123.0   simple=123.0
123.25  123.25  simple=123.25
123.3   123.25  simple=123.25
123.48  123.25  simple=123.25
123.5   123.5   simple=123.5
123.72  123.5   simple=123.5
123.75  123.75  simple=123.75
123.86  123.75  simple=123.75
```